# Scaling Property of the Proximal Operator

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, subgradient, proximal-operators

If the proximal operator of $f(x)$ is $\text{prox}_{\lambda f}(x)$, what about $cf(x)$ and $f(cx)$, c is a scalar.

For example, If $f(x) = ||x||_{1}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, how about the proximal operator of $c||x||_{1}$ and $||c x||_{1}$.

Comment: Related - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631130.

Answer (score 2):

Part 1: Note that $\text{prox}_{t(cf)}(x) = \text{ prox } _ { (tc) f}(x)$.

Part 2: Let $ g (x) = f ( cx) $.
To evaluate $\text{prox}_{tg}(y)$, we must find a minimizer of 
\begin{equation}
f (cx) + (1/2t) \|x - y \|^2.
\end{equation}
Make the change of variable $ z = cx $. Our optimization problem is equivalent to minimizing
\begin{equation}
f(z) + (1/2t) \| z/c - y\|^2 
\end{equation}
with respect to $ z $.
The best choice of $ z $ is the prox operator of $ f $ at $ cy $ with parameter $ t c^2$.
The corresponding best choice of $ x $ is $ z/c $.

\begin{equation}
\text{prox}_{tg}(y)
= \text{prox}_{tc^2f}(cy)/c.
\end{equation}

Comment: You were of course correct about mine! I'm deleting it. I can't even blame a lack of caffeine.

Comment: You should also post your answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774137.